# How to prevent the Overwrite Prompt while saving in custome IFileDialoge - VC++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, save-dialog

I don't want to display any overwrite prompt while user enter the file name which is already  exist in my custom `IFileDialog`.

I have already gone throw [`IFileDialog::SetOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method but it dint solve my problem.

`FOS_OVERWRITEPROMPT (0x00000002)` : When saving a file, prompt before overwriting an existing file of the same name. This is a default value for the Save dialog.

IS there any flag which help me out from this issue..??
Or is there any other way to prevent the overwrite prompt while saving the file.

Please help me. Many thanks in advance..:)

Comment: It's not very clear what you did -- did you call `IFileDialog::SetOptions(0)` to reset the value?

Comment: By default `IFileDialog` gives overwrite prompt, even `FOS_OVERWRITEPROMPT` flag is not set..

Comment: I haven't used `IFileDialog` myself, but [CFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh5hz49d(v=vs.100).aspx) works with `dwFlags` set to `OFN_HIDEREADONLY`

Comment: `CFileDialog` does not work in Win7, 
I mean `OnInitDialog()` method of `CFileDialog` does not call in Win7, So that I am using `IFileDialog`. Is there any flag in `IFileDialog` ???

Comment: The [documentation for CFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7(v=vs.100).aspx) says `OnInitDialog` inherited function is not supported under Windows Vista (or later) -- do you do anything special in `OnInitDialog()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    HRESULT hr;
    DWORD dwFlags = 0;

//pDlg is your IFileSaveDialog
    hr = pDlg->GetOptions ( &dwFlags );
    if( dwFlags & FOS_OVERWRITEPROMPT )
    {
        dwFlags = dwFlags & ( ~FOS_OVERWRITEPROMPT);
        hr = pDlg->SetOptions ( dwFlags );
    }
```